# How to speed up 3 channel image convolution in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization, convolution

I'm using convolution for neural networks, currently it's being implemented like this

```
for f = 1:NumberOfKernels
    tempC = conv2(input(:,:,1),kernels(:,:,1,f),'same');
    tempM = conv2(input(:,:,2),kernels(:,:,2,f),'same');
    tempY = conv2(input(:,:,3),kernels(:,:,3,f),'same');
    preactivation(:,:,f) = tempC + tempM + tempY;
end
```

Can this be done in a single line without writing out conv2 for each color channel individually? Can [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) function from Image Processing Toolbox speed it up? Take into account that I have no GPU.

Comment: If you do not have a GPU, the GPU enabled functions will not work. That's like asking if you can cycle to work, providing you do not have a bicycle.

Comment: If the kernel is the same for all channels, you can use `convn` once.

Comment: Have you tried `imfilter` (it does not require a GPU)? @rayryeng: if all of the kernels are the same, one could take advantage of the [distributivity of convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Algebraic_properties) and possibly use a single `conv2` here, no?

Comment: @horchler - Ah, yes. I didn't think about it that way. That can work.

Comment: Kernels are not the same for all channels, if that was so it would be insensitive to colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
szk = size(kernels);
temp =  zeros(size(input)+szk(1:3)-1);
szk = ceil(szk(1:2) / 2);
temp(szk(1):szk(1)-1+size(input,1),szk(2):szk(2)-1+size(input,2),:) = input;
for f = 1:NumberOfKernels
   preactivation(:,:,f) = convn(temp,kernels(:,:,:,f),'valid');
end
```

However, I wouldn't expect it to be much faster. What would make things faster was if the kernels were separable.

Comment: What does it mean for kernels to be separable?

Comment: Search for "separable filter"

Comment: Well it didn't speed up but thank you anyways I did accept sorry for being late :D